# Integral of $L1$ function against compactly supported smooth function:

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have the following intuition, which I am not sure about if it is true or not, since I cannot come up with a proof or with a counterexample.

> Given an $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, if $$\int_\mathbb{R}f \cdot \phi = 0, \forall\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$$
>   then we have $f = 0$ (in the sense of equivalence classes).

Does anyone know a proof of this? And if the integral evaluates to for example $\phi(1)$ does it still hold that $f=0$?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The answer depends on how much you know about the integral. Do you know the Lebesgue differentiation theorem? Or that the set of continuous functions is dense in $L^1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to prove with this condition that for all $[a,b]$ (it is easy to construct a sequence $\phi_n\rightarrow 1_{[a,b]} $, with $\phi_n$ smooth with compact support, by convolution and then use dominating theorem (since $f$ is in $L^1$))
$$ \int f1_{[a,b]} =0.$$
And then since the borelian $\sigma$-algebra is generated by $\{[a,b],\ a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}$ you will have
$$ \int f 1_A =\int_A f =0,\quad \forall A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$
which implies easily (take $A=\{f>0\}$ and then $A'=\{f<0\}$, you will have $\lambda(A)=\lambda(A')=0$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure) the result.

Comment: How do I then modify the proof if instead of the integral evaluating to 0 I have that it evaluates to for example $\phi(1)$ as in the second question?

Comment: @vaoy I am sorry, I don't understand what you mean : can you give me the full statement you want to eventually prove?

Comment: Is it still true, if $\int_\mathbb{R}f \cdot \phi = \phi(1), \forall\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ we have that $f=0$? I changed $0$ with $\phi(1)$

Comment: @vaoy Hell no! That is not true at all! If it were, you will have $\forall \phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$, $$ \int f\cdot \phi = \int 0\cdot \phi = 0=\phi(1)$$ which is absurd.

Comment: And what if we consider only test functions $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ with $\phi(1)=0$?

Comment: @vaoy it this case the same demonstration works fine : indeed for every $a,b$, you can construct a sequence $(\phi_n)$ of such functions such that $$\phi_n\rightarrow 1_{[a,b]\setminus\{0\}} $$ and you will have then $$\int f 1_{[a,b]\setminus\{0\}}=0$$ But since $\int f 1_{[a,b]\setminus\{0\}}=\int f 1_{[a,b]\setminus\{0\}}+\underbrace{\int_{\{0\}}f}_{=0}=\int f 1_{[a,b]}$, you have again $$\int f 1_{[a,b]}=0$$ for all $a,b$ and you can finish the proof the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Let $r>0.$ Then there exists a sequence $\phi_n$ of smooth functions, supported in $[-r,r],$ with $0 \le \phi_n\le 1$ for all $n,$ such that $\phi_n(x) \to \text { sgn }f(x)$ for a.e. $x\in [-r,r].$ It follows from the DCT that

$$0=\int_{-r}^r \phi_n f \to \int_{-r}^r(\text {sgn }f)\cdot f =\int_{-r}^r |f|.$$

Thus $ \int_{-r}^r |f|=0.$ Since $r$ is arbitrary, $\int_{\mathbb R} |f|= 0.$ Hence $f=0$ a.e.

Answer (score 0):

Choose a sequence of uniformly bounded smooth functions $\phi_n$ with support in $[-1,2]$ that converge pointwise to $1_{[0,1]}$. Then
$0=\int f \phi_n \to \int f 1_{[0,1]} = 0$.

Hence $\int_a^t f= 0$ for any $a,t$, hence Lebesgue's differentiation theorem shows that we have $f=0$ ae.