# existence of the convolution with a continuously differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convolution

It is well known (using Fubini's theorem) that the convolution of two $f,g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ functions is again in $L^1$, and thus $$ f \ast g(x)=\int_\mathbb{R}{f(x-t)g(t)dt}$$
converges for almost all *$x$.
I wanted to ask*: in case $g\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ is continuously differentiable with a bounded derivative (or even integrable if necessary), does this necessarily imply that the integral defining $f \ast g(x)$ converges *for all* $x \in \mathbb{R}$? I am trying to find a minimal condition (not strong properties like compact support) for the integral to converge everywhere.

Comment: What are your assumptions on $f$ or is it part of your question what assumptions on $f$ guarantee the well-definedness of a convolution for all continuous $g$?

Comment: If $ g$ is bounded then $\int_\mathbb{R} |h(x)g(x)|dx< \infty$ for any $h\in L^1$. That $g$ is bounded is indeed the minimal condition for $f \ast g$ to be bounded and continuous if you only know that $f \in L^1$. If $g$ isn't bounded you can still have that $f \ast g$ is bounded and/or continuous for many (but not all) $f \in L^1$

Comment: @JonasLenz I don't think assuming more than "f is integrable" is needed, you can see for example this post: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3029627/convolution-of-a-compactly-supported-function-and-an-l1-function/3030816#3030816]

Comment: @reuns indeed if g is bounded the problem is solved (do you have reference as to why $f \ast g$ is continues in this case? what about a reference to the cases where it is valid only for some special $f \in L^1$?). I am quite happy with that, though I think I also came up with the solution in case g is integrable and uniformly continues, not sure if this implies boundness.

Comment: $f \ast g$ is continuous because $f(.+1/n) \to f$ in $L^1$ (a consequence of that the compactly supported continuous functions are dense in $L^1$)